# ng serve not compiling

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I get this trying to run my local server with `ng serve`:

```
[error] Error: NGCC failed.
    at NgccProcessor.process (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:129:19)
    at compiler.hooks.thisCompilation.tap (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/plugin.js:112:27)
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:630:30)
    at hooks.beforeCompile.callAsync.err (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:667:29)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compiler.compile (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:662:28)
    at compiler.hooks.watchRun.callAsync.err (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:77:18)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Watching._go (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:41:32)
    at Watching.compiler.readRecords.err (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:33:9)
    at Compiler.readRecords (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:529:11)
    at new Watching (/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:30:17)
```

As I'm not very familiar with the JS/ npm world, I was wondering if it was common and easily fixable or should I just re-install things from scratch.

Before having this issue, I ran out of disk space installing some npm packages causing this error:

```
54 verbose stack Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/@angular/core' -> '/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/@angular/.core-KuljwpJv'
55 verbose cwd /home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front
56 verbose Linux 5.8.0-50-generic
57 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "@angular/animations" "--save"
58 verbose node v10.19.0
59 verbose npm  v7.12.0
60 error code ENOTEMPTY
61 error syscall rename
62 error path /home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/@angular/core
63 error dest /home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/@angular/.core-KuljwpJv
64 error errno -39
65 error ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/@angular/core' -> '/home/geoffroy/Documents/1_projets_persos/35_ngodt/ngodt-front/node_modules/@angular/.core-KuljwpJv'
66 verbose exit -39
```

probably due to a folder lock and Im pretty sure this is the root of my issue.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I made some free space in my disk, rebooted my laptop, tryied to install my package with sudo. Finally I removed the node_module filte and run ```npm install``` and every things are all right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted `/node_modules`

then I installed dependencies with

```
npm install
```

And the problem was solved